# Is there pointer in C# like C++? Is it safe?

Tags: c#, c++, data-structures, tree

I'm writing an application that work with a tree data structure. I've written it with C++, now i want to write it by C#. I use pointers for implementing the tree data structure. Is there a pointer in C# too? Is it safe to use it?

Comment: Please, could you first search for these keywords on SO and ask only the stuff that is not yet covered.

Comment: code with pointers must be tagged 'unsafe', guess why.

Comment: Actually using pointers is NOT safe anywhere ;)

Comment: @Machine Charmer - its only unsafe if you don't know what you're doing (unfortunately you usually work with people who don't know what they're doing)

Comment: This is one article which I found easy to follow. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/usingpointers10022007082330AM/usingpointers.aspx

Comment: Anything pointy is unsafe!  Pointers are like knives. They are inherently unsafe but they CAN be used safely. You shouldn't need them in C# but if you insist on using them you have use the 'unsafe' keyword to tell the compiler you know what you're doing and it's your resposibility to make sure that section of code doesn't misbehave.

Comment: Going out into the street, driving, flying are all not safe!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you're implementing a tree structure in C# (or Java, or many other languages) you'd use references instead of pointers. NB. references in C++ are not the same as these references.

The usage is similar to pointers for the most part, but there are advantages like garbage collection.

```
class TreeNode
{
    private TreeNode parent, firstChild, nextSibling;

    public InsertChild(TreeNode newChild)
    {
        newChild.parent = this;
        newChild.nextSibling = firstChild;
        firstChild = newChild;
    }
}

var root = new TreeNode();
var child1 = new TreeNode();
root.InsertChild(child1);
```

Points of interest:

- No need to modify the type with `*` when declaring the members
- No need to set them to null in a constructor (they're already null)
- No special `->` operator for member access
- No need to write a destructor (although look up `IDisposable`)

Comment: Important difference between pointers and references: The latter doesn't support pointer arithmetic!

Comment: @Joachim - let's all pray he doesn't normally use pointer arithmetic in his tree structures.

Comment: This answer does not address the actual question. Came here from a google search, and fortunately others had actually answered the question...

Answer (score 36):

**YES**. There are pointers in C#.

**NO**. They are **NOT** safe.

You actually have to use keyword **`unsafe`** when you use pointers in C#.

For examples look **[here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Language-Basics/Pointer-Unsafe.htm)** and **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8%28VS.71%29.aspx)**.

```
static unsafe void Increment(int* i)
{
    *i++;
}

Increment(&count);
```

Use this instead and code will be SAFE and CLEAN.

```
static void Increment(ref int i)
{
    i++;
}

Increment(ref count);
```

Answer (score 22):

> Is there pointer in C# too?

[Yes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/pointer-types), declared using the syntax `int* varName;`.

> Is using of that safe?

No pointers are **not safe**.

There are safe ways to construct a data structure without pointers. If the nodes are classes, then they'll automatically be [reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) so you don't need any pointers. Otherwise, you can [box them into a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Comment: Interesting answer. Unfortunately, the link to the yes part seems broken (i.e. Download of full vs 2005 doc instead of specific language feature).  The boxing/unboxing gives the impression that it's safe; why isn't it ?

Comment: @Christophe Thanks, fixed the broken links. Also clarified the wordings, that boxing/unobxing are safe ways to avoid the unsafe pointers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a pointer:
[IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr(VS.71).aspx)

Wikipedia: ["which is a safe managed equivalent to int*, and does not require unsafe code"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computing)#C.23)

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/11/11/properly-incrementing-an-intptr.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is a great series of Data Structures implemented in .Net on Microsoft Docs.

[Data Structures Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/)

They include sample code for things like Binary Search Tree, Graph, SkipList, NodeList, etc.  The code is quite complete and includes a number of pages of docs about why these structures work, etc.

None of the ones from Microsoft use pointers.  In general, you never NEED to use them in C#.  There are times when using them would be nice, or they are just the way you think from C++.  But you can usually find a way not to use them.

The biggest reasons why not to use unsafe code for pointers is that you lose Medium Trust compliance.  You can't run through mechanisms like click once, asp.net websites, and Silverlight doesn't allow them either.  Stick with refs and fully managed concepts to ensure your code can run in more places.

Comment: The link is no longer supported

Comment: Fixed the link, hope that helps someone.