# Reference to reference in C#

Tags: c#, reference

In C# I want to pass a reference to an object that is not yet instantiated. Like this:

```
    MyClass obj = new MyClass(obj);
```

In C++ I could do it like this:

```
    class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass( MyClass **obj ) : the_obj( obj ) { }
        MyClass** the_obj;
    };
    MyClass *obj = new MyClass(&obj);
```

How do I do that in C#?

Regards.

Comment: Do you want an object that references itself?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? By the way, C# has pointers. See [Is there pointer in C# like C++? Is it safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333574)

Comment: Pointers should be used as a last resort, in my opinion.

Comment: It would really help if you explained [what you are trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/), not what mechanism you have decided to use.

Comment: When you get into problems with the language such as this, it is generally a sign that it is not the right approach (at least for the language you are using). There may be an alternative solution to what you are trying to achieve. If you could provide details as to what your end goal is, we could perhaps assist with some alternatives

Comment: Is this about using uninitialized references, or about references of references resp. pointers of pointers?

Comment: Yes. I want sn object that references itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a mutable class that has a reference to the type you are interested in as a member:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
Wrapper<MyClass> wrapper = new Wrapper<MyClass>();
```

You now have a reference to an instance with a reference to an instance of `MyClass`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider It's named `wrapper`.  It is a reference to an uninitialized reference to a `MyClass`.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes, it does, and that object is itself a reference, because it's a reference type.  This is the moral equivalent of a pointer in C/C++.

Comment: The field underlying Wrapper's automatic property `Value` is null, isn't it?

Comment: @PeterSchneider At first, yes.  It can be assigned an instance.  The fact that it's null is what makes it a pointer to an uninitialized pointer, which is what was specifically asked for.